# How does a missing src attribute in an img tag behave across browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I have a page with many images hidden inside a set of disclosures.  When you click on the title of the section, the image (as well as other things) appears.  So far so good.  However, there are many of these images, which leads to ridiculous loading times, so I want to load them only when they need to be displayed.  When I open the section, I check whether the `src` of the image is set, and if it isn't, I set it and the image loads.  I have found, however, that if I omit the `src` attribute of my `<img>`, Javascript (in Chrome) considers it `=== ''`.  It's identical to the empty string!  I would have expected it to be `undefined`.

This is pretty nice, but it seems a bit too nice.  How do different browsers evaluate `img.src` when `img` is an `<img>` tag without a `src`?  If I check that `img.src === ''`, is this safe on other browsers?

Comment: It's not very tough, you can check on other browsers. Can't you ? May be checking `img.src === '' || img.src === undefined` would be right ?

Comment: `img.src` checks the property, not the attribute. You can check the attribute via `img.getAttribute('src')`

Comment: images have a event called `onerror` . you can handle that from this event... it will check for src empty also: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_onerror

Comment: If you're already using jQuery you may need to look @ `lazyLoad` or `unveil.js`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check it like this:

```
if (!img.src) {
    // need to set the .src property here
}
```

Since this checks for any falsey value, this will cover you no matter whether the browser returns `null`, `undefined` or `""`.

FYI, I tried [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5ZQ8b/) in Firefox, Chrome and IE and they all returned the empty string for the `.src` property, but checking for any falsey value as above will make your code more permissible if some older version of some browser has a slightly different idea.

Answer (score 0):

For all the modern browsers, an image with no `SRC` is complete. But, according to IE, an image with no `SRC` is not complete - `is not loaded`. You could use [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getAttribute) to check if `src` attribute exists. Like:

```
if( !img.getAttribute('src') ) {
    //the img does not have src attribute
}
```